# Is the sentence 'such a gift is more pronounce in childhood' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, tenses

I understand that 'in childhood' is something that happened in the past. However, the meaning that I want to convey is that the 'gift being pronounce in childhood' is a fact. Can I then use 'pronounce' in its present tense?

Comment: If you mean that some talent is pronounced in childhood (maybe someone is a child prodigy), then the word "pronounced" is not a verb, it is an adjective. Adjectives don't have a tense.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica, I think adjectives, sometimes, have tense. E.g., Present Tense, Past Tense, Future Tense... ;) ;) ;)

Comment: @RamPillai Yes, we all know what tenses are, but adjectives don't have them. Can you give an example of what you think is an adjective in the past tense?

Comment: @KateBunting; it was an intended humor to say that the words present, past and future are qualifiers to the common term tense.  Adjectives also are qualifiers in some way.  Just like that... :)

Answer (score 1):

"In childhood" is not always past. If you are talking about a baby "childhood" will be in the future. You need to use the continuous present when describing indefinite times.

However that is not really an issue. The sentence you write is incorrect, because the verb "pronounce" is not what you should be using, but the adjective "pronounced" (which is spelled like but does not have the same meaning or part of speech as the past tense of "pronounce"). The adjective doesn't change with tense.

> Such a gift is more pronounced in childhood

is the correct sentence. If you know the time frame and want to put it in the past or future

> Such a gift *was* more pronounced in childhood

> Such a gift *will be* more pronounced in childhood

Comment: Thank you, that answers it.

Comment: If this answers your question please vote it up (up arrow button) and accept it (tick button).